# spn command failing due to a period in service account name

Tags: active-directory, windows-server-2012, spn

we are required to have a .svc in our service accounts i.e

aduser.svc

the following spn command is failing

```
setspn -a SPNName/aduser.svc.domain.com aduser.svc
```

unknown parameter, please check your usage.

Any ideas on how to get around that?

Answer (score 0):

What's the service class name in the SPN, is it HTTP?  Using "SPNName" as shown is incorrect.  An SPN name is the entire string "HTTP/aduser.svc.domain.com", not just the first part preceding the "/".  Assuming the service name is HTTP, the correct example is shown below:

```
setspn -a HTTP/aduser.svc.domain.com aduser.svc
```

Also note, `setspn -s` is the preferred syntax, because it finds duplicates, rather than `setspn -a` which is the older usage and no longer recommended.